# -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue not working

Tags: powershell

I'm working with powershell I'm calling a script from c#.
I'm trying to copy logs from different servers,

```
foreach($server in $args)
{
    $destination = "\\$server\$path"
    if(!(Test-Path $destination))
        {
            New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $destination
        }
    foreach($log in $logsTaskAgent)
    {
        Write-Host "Backup $log log $server"



        $filename = "{0}{1}_{2}_{3}.evt" -f $destination,$server,$log,$date
        Write-Host "Filename: $filename"

        if($password -and $userName)
        {
            $logFile = Get-WmiObject Win32_NTEventlogFile -ComputerName $server -Credential $credential -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | where-object { $_.logfilename -eq $log } 
            Write-Output "continue"
            if($logFile)
            {
                $logFile.PSBase.Scope.Options.EnablePrivileges = $true 
                $logFile.backupeventlog($filename) 
            }
            else
            {
                Write-Output "Error on server: $server for log: $log"
            }
        }


    }
```

### This works perfectly, but when something is wrong with the credentials it throw an exception but I want to continue because has I said, I have many servers so I just want to ignore the exception and continue with the other servers any idea  of what is wrong? As far has I understand -ErrorAction Silentlycontinue should do the trick but it's not :(

Edit: Fix

I ended up with something very similar to the answer of Johan de Haan so I would take that as the answer... here's the code modified:

```
foreach($server in $args)
{

    try
    {
        $destination = "\\$server\$path"
        if(!(Test-Path $destination))
            {
                New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $destination
            }
        foreach($log in $logsTaskAgent)
        {
            Write-Host "Backup $log log $server"



            $filename = "{0}{1}_{2}_{3}.evt" -f $destination,$server,$log,$date
            Write-Host "Filename: $filename"

            if($password -and $userName)
            {
                $logFile = Get-WmiObject Win32_NTEventlogFile -ComputerName $server -Credential $credential -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | where-object { $_.logfilename -eq $log } 
                Write-Output "continue"
                if($logFile)
                {
                    $logFile.PSBase.Scope.Options.EnablePrivileges = $true 
                    $logFile.backupeventlog($filename) 
                }
                else
                {
                    Write-Output "Error on server: $server for log: $log"
                }
            }


        }
    }
    catch
    {
        Write-Output "Error while retrieving log Object from server $server : $($_.Exception.Message)"
        continue
    }

    $destination = ""
}
```

Comment: If you want to completely suppress all error output, then use a Try/Catch and use `-EA Stop`, and then do nothing in your Catch block.

Comment: Thanks, I don't want to suppress, I want to continue with the next server, going to update the code so you can see the loop.

Comment: @user1216761, Ryan Riles's suggestion will do what you want if you wrap the offending code in the `try`/`catch`. You can also try `-ea Ignore`, or perhaps the error is already being ignored but it's the `where-object` that is failing? It would help if you posted the error. Also this code looks incomplete. You reference `$userName` and `$password` in the `if` but never use them, and you use `$credential` in the cmdlet call, but never define it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make use of a try/catch and use a break to continue with next server:

```psh
foreach($server in $args){
    $destination = "\\$server\$path"
    if(!(Test-Path $destination))
    {
        New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $destination
    }
    foreach($log in $logsTaskAgent)
    {
        Write-Host "Backup $log log $server"

        $filename = "{0}{1}_{2}_{3}.evt" -f $destination,$server,$log,$date
        Write-Host "Filename: $filename"

        if($password -and $userName) {
            try{
                 $logFile = Get-WmiObject Win32_NTEventlogFile -ComputerName $server -Credential $credential -ErrorAction Stop | where-object { $_.logfilename -eq $log } 
            } catch {
                 Write-Warning "Error while retrieving WMI Object: $($_.Exception.Message)"
                 break #this way you break out of the first loop, continuing in the foreach ($server in args loop)
            }

            Write-Output "continue"
            if($logFile) {
                $logFile.PSBase.Scope.Options.EnablePrivileges = $true 
                $logFile.backupeventlog($filename) 
            } else {
                Write-Output "Error on server: $server for log: $log"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm going to take this as the correct answer, I figure it out yesterday night and end up with something very similar to this, I will update my post, thanks